# Prove via induction $\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{k-1}{k!}} = \frac{n!-1}{n!}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$

Tags: induction

I have to prove by induction, that

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{k-1}{k!}} = \frac{n!-1}{n!}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$$

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}{\frac{k-1}{k!}} &= \sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{k-1}{k!} + \frac{(n+1)-1}{(n+1)!}} \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{k-1}{k!} + \frac{n}{(n+1)!}} \\
&= \frac{n!-1}{n!} + \frac{n}{(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{[n!-1](n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!} + \frac{n! \cdot n}{n!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{[n!-1](n+1)! + n! \cdot n}{n!(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{n!(n+1)!-(n+1)!+n!n}{n!(n+1)!} \\
\end{align}$

**Question:** How should I go on ? Do I have a mistake until now?

Comment: Just telescope: $\frac{k-1}{k!}= \frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: Hint: The common denominator of $\frac 1{n!}$ and $\frac 1{(n+1)!}$ is much smaller

Comment: You are overcomplicating it: $$\frac{k-1}{k!} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}$$ is a telescopic term, hence the final outcome ($1-\frac{1}{n!}$) is clear.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OP said he wants to prove via induction.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: same story, $$ \left(1-\frac{1}{n!}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right) = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your third line:

\begin{align}
\frac{n!-1}{n!} + \frac{n}{(n+1)!} &= \frac{(n!-1)(n+1)}{n!(n+1)}+\frac{n}{(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(n+1)!-(n+1)+n}{(n+1)!} \\
&=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}
\end{align}

Don't forget to check base case.

To go on from where you stop, divide numerator and denominator by $n!$.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect up to this point; to continue, write the middle $(n+1)!$ in the numerator as $(n+1)n!$, then cancel the $n!$ from the denominator.